# FMU from Dymola to Energyplus

Tags: compiler-construction, export, dymola, energyplus

I want to simulate a system created in Dymola with a building created in energyplus. I'm following the guide for the functional mock up.
I exported the FMU file from Dymola and i made it compatible with Eplus thanks to FMI parser.
When i run the co-simulation Eplus show me the following error:

> ExternalInterface/InitExternalInterfaceFMUImport: Error when trying to
>   load FMI functions library of instance [..]. Check FMU binaries folder
>   and see whether libraries exist for the system architecture of the
>   EnergyPlus version used.

I can't understand what is the name of the instance to use (FMU instance name). Is it the name of dll file?

Moreover in the FMU binaries folders i've a dll file for win32 and not for 64-bit.
I use visual studio 2010 express edition and if i test it on dymola the program say me that it's not possible to compile 64-bit dymosim.
Can this be the problem? Can you suggest me another compiler for dymola that can build 64-bit dymosim?

Thank you!

Comment: Which version of the generated FMUs (1.0 2.0Beta4 or 2.0RC1)? You can find that info unzipping the FMU file and looking into the modelDescription.xml file. The fact that you exported only for 32 bit can be a throuble if Eplus works at 64bits, I suggest you to download Download and install the Windows Software Development Kit version 7.1. Visual C++ 2010 Express does not include a 64 bit compiler, but the SDK does. A link to the SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb980924.aspx . I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! In the modelDescription file i found fmiVersion=1.0 that is the version i chosen in dymola. 
Now i have SDK component and VCUpgrade tool, but i can't understand how to use it in order to produce FMU file at 64 bits.

Comment: I suppose you are using the "Building Controls Virtual Test Bed" tool to perform the Co-simulation, am I right? In this case here: http://simulationresearch.lbl.gov/bcvtb/releases/latest/doc/manual/tit-FMUCon.xhtml I read that you should be compliant since the tool imports FMU version 1.0 for Co-Simulation. Have you tried if it works with the examples? In order to use the 64bits compiler you have only to install the sdk and perform the check of the compiler again in Dymola to be sure that it works well.

Comment: No, i'm using the functional mock up for co-simulation http://eetd.lbl.gov/publications/functional-mock-up-unit-import-in-ene I followed the paper and i set the new idf file as described but when i try to run the simulation energyplus show me the error above.

Comment: Then maybe you are using Energyplus 64 bit, and it requires 64bit fmus. Did you manage to compile 64bit FMUs with Dymola?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I've installed SDK 7.1 following the instruction but my dymola compiler still continues to produce only 32-bit FMUs.
In Visual Studio 10.0 folder anyway i can see SDK folder but if opened there is only v3.5 folder and is empty. Do i need to exported some files from the Microsoft SDK folder??

Comment: The sdk should have installed a folder named something like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64

Comment: I just had an issue with my laptop and had to reinstall everything, if you install vs 2012 express, it will work and generate 64bits dll without any other sdk needed.